# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'imageUrl') Angular material

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material

When I write this line of html code:

```
<td> <img align="center" [src]="productByBarCode.imageUrl" /> </td>
```

The console throws the following error:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading
> 'imageUrl')

`imageUrl` is of type string and it is an url. I'm using Angular material. How can I deal with it?

.html file:

```
<table>

        <!-- Image Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="img">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef></th>
    <td> <img align="center" [src]="productByBarCode.imageUrl" /> </td>
  </ng-container>

...

</table>
```

.ts file:

```
export class ProductDetailsComponent implements OnInit {
  public productByBarCode!: Product;
  displayedColumns = ['img', 'name', 'description', 'price', 'quantity', 'add to cart'];
  constructor(private _snackBar: MatSnackBar, private shared: SharedService, private productService: ProductService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.shared.castByBarCode.subscribe(productByBarCode=>this.productByBarCode=productByBarCode);
...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can only assume that your "shared" service isn't resolving `productByBarCode` variable before view tries to reach it. In that case your code is trying to resolve `imageUrl` from `null`.

You can just *ngIf check if `productByBarCode` is truthy/falsy like this:

```
<td>
    <img *ngIf="productByBarCode" align="center [src]="productByBarCode.imageUrl" />
</td>
```

After this if your image still isn't resolving, just `console.log` your `productByBarCode` variable to check whats inside :)