# Angular Cannot read properties of undefined in html

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm an angular rookie and working on getting better at it.

I have the three files where I'm using a service(**Studentservice.ts**) which emits an observable(**ShowBeerDetails method**) and I later subscribe to it in my component(**Beer-details.component.ts**).

I made sure that I'm receiving the observable values by console logging in my components onInit method and the value of beerObj prints just fine.

The issue is I get the below error in my HTML when the view is loaded. I think the reason is shared service isn't resolving beerObj variable before view tries to reach it.(I may be wrong about this).

I tried adding <div *ngIf="beerobj"> statement which prevents the console error but since beerObj still remains undefined I'm not seeing my values(name, price, and Id) printed.

I'm not sure to fix this. I have read multiple SF questions but none helped me.
[ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'imageUrl') Angular material](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71084456/error-typeerror-cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-reading-imageurl-angula)

[image]

**Studentservice.ts**

```
import { EventEmitter, Injectable, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { studentInterface } from './studentInterface';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { beer } from './beerInterface';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class StudentService {

  constructor(private _http:HttpClient) { }
  private _url="../assets/data/student.json";

  getStudents(): Observable<studentInterface[]>{  
//return [{"id":1, "name":"Rama"},{"id":2, "name":"Bheema"},{"id":3, "name":"Hanuman"}];

return this._http.get<studentInterface[]>(this._url);

}

getBeerList(): Observable<beer[]>{

  return this._http.get<beer[]>('https://api.sampleapis.com/beers/ale');
}

@Output() OnShowDetailsClicked= new EventEmitter<beer>;

ShowBeerDetails(beerobj:beer){
  console.log('Value of beer passed in showuserdetials'+beerobj.name);
this.OnShowDetailsClicked.emit(beerobj);
}
}
```

**Beer-details.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, ParamMap } from '@angular/router';
import { beer } from '../beerInterface';
import { StudentService } from '../student.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-beer-details',
  templateUrl: './beer-details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./beer-details.component.css']
})
export class BeerDetailsComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private _activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,private _stdservice:StudentService) { }

  beerobj!: beer;
  myname:string="sreemanth";

  ngOnInit(): void {


    this._stdservice.OnShowDetailsClicked.subscribe((data:beer)=>{
      this.beerobj=data;
      console.log('Value set to beer in subscribe'+this.beerobj.name);
      console.log('the emitted beer value in subscribe'+data.name)});

  }
}
```

**Student.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, ParamMap, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Beer } from '../beerInterface';
import { StudentService } from '../student.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-student',
  templateUrl: './student.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./student.component.css']
})


export class StudentComponent implements OnInit {

public selectedid:any;
public beers:Beer[]=[];


  constructor(private _router: Router,private _activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,private _stdservice:StudentService) {

   }



  ngOnInit(): void {

    this._stdservice.getBeerList().subscribe(data=>this.beers=data);


    this._activatedRoute.paramMap.subscribe((params: ParamMap) =>{
      let id=parseInt(params.get('id')||'');
      this.selectedid=id;
    });
  
  }

  onselect(x: { id: any; }){
//this._router.navigate(['/studentdetails',x.id])
this._router.navigate([x.id],{relativeTo:this._activatedRoute})
  }


  onBeerselect(x:Beer){
    console.log('Value of beer passed'+x.id);
    this._stdservice.ShowBeerDetails(x);
    this._router.navigate(['/beer-list',x.id])
   // this._router.navigate([x.id],{relativeTo:this._activatedRoute})
      }


  isSelected(x:any){
return x.id===this.selectedid;

  }

  public studentdetials=[
{"id":1,"name":"sreemanth","grade":"A"},
{"id":2,"name":"robert","grade":"B"},
{"id":3,"name":"karim","grade":"C"}
  ];

}
```

**beer-details.component.html**

```
<!--<div *ngIf="beerobj">-->
<p>beer-details works!</p>
<p>{{beerobj.name}}</p>
<p>{{beerobj.price}}</p>
<p>{{beerobj.id}}</p>
<!--</div>-->
```

I have checked my code at https://github.com/Jasti4Git/helloworld

Answer (score 0):

My guess is: The following assignment inside the subscribe block is asynchronous. If any parent component has onPush change detection strategy, the beer.component one has the same change detection strategy as well. Ifo that's the case, Angular won't know that the value changed and there is no reason (for Angular) to update the view.

So you could try to inject the `changeDetectorRef` in the constructor and call `changeDetectorRef.detectChanges` after the assignment to beerobj inside the constructor. Please check if that helps.

Sidenote: the 'beer' type is class or interface, so it should be 'Beer'.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your Angular version, a simple way to printing values at the html, from an mutable structure, is adding the keyword '?' before the param

**beer-details.component.html**

```
<p>beer-details works!</p>
<p>{{beerobj?.name}}</p>
<p>{{beerobj?.price}}</p>
<p>{{beerobj?.id}}</p>
```

however your ngIf solution should have been working. Check your angular Change Detection Strategy, if in a parent component is setting to `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` so in your html you should do as:

**beer-details.component.html**

```
<div *ngIf="_stdservice.OnShowDetailsClicked | async as beerobj">
    <p>beer-details works!</p>
    <p>{{beerobj.name}}</p>
    <p>{{beerobj.price}}</p>
    <p>{{beerobj.id}}</p>
</div>
```

But you need to make your `StudentService` as public in your constructor

Comment: The angular version I'm using is 14. When I try to use the keyword '?', I'm presented with this error -"The left side of this optional chain operation does not include 'null' or 'undefined' in its type, therefore the '?.' operator can be replaced with the '.' operator.ngtsc(-998107)".   Regarding Change Detection, I don't think I have explicitly configured anything and I believe angular is using default.

Comment: To the keyword '?' works, you need to remove the '!' from `beerobj!: beer;` (here you are affirming that its not undefined, but it is). Maybe that is the problem, if you could check it, and answare againg, would be great

Comment: I updated my code and am now able to use '?' operator after changing beerobj initialization to 'beerobj: Beer | undefined'.   But the main issue still persists, I'm still not able to see properties of beerObj(name, price, and ID) printing in HTML.

Comment: Have you tried the second part? Utilizing `_stdservice.OnShowDetailsClicked | async as beerobj`. It alse work in Default Change Detection

Comment: Unfortunately, it's the same result after using '_stdservice.OnShowDetailsClicked | async as beerobj' and making my service public in the constructor. I'm still not able to see the properties of beerObj(name, price, and ID) printing in HTML. I have added the other component(student.component.ts) which is actually calling my service before routing to the beer-details component for reference.

Comment: I have checked in my code at https://github.com/Jasti4Git/helloworld